# How do I use token to give access to my Telegram bot to another person?

Tags: bots, telegram

I made a bot and have a token for it. If I give it to another administrator, what should they do with the token to access the bot?

Thanks

Comment: Which kind of bot, what did you try?

Comment: I made a bot using BotFather and added some functionality using @LivegramBot. It's a simple bot that asks users questions and records answers.

Answer (score 1):

When you are prompting a message form your code, you need to pass the token in some way for authentication. Usually for sending messages you should provide a url that includes your token as such:

```
url = TELEGRAM_HOSTNAME + "/bot" + token + "/sendMessage"
requests.post(url, data="message in json format with chat_id and keyboard options")
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't do any actual coding, I just used @LivegramBot to add functionality.